# Conjugate direction field definition?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-fields

I'm trying to find any reference that defines what a "conjugate direction field" is. I think this is a topic of differential geometry, but I can't find any reference for this, I have many papers that mention this concept but none of them provides a good definition or reference I can look up.

Is there any reference you can suggest to understand the topic?

Answer (score 0):

The context with which I am familiar is this: Given a surface $S$ in $\Bbb R^3$, its second fundamental form $\mathbf{II}$ defines a symmetric bilinear form on each tangent space. We say tangent vectors $v$ and $w$ at $p\in S$ are *conjugate*
if $\mathbf{II}_p(v,w)=0$.  (So, on a round sphere, this would just be saying that they're orthogonal in $\Bbb R^3$.)

For an interesting application of this, see Exercise 20 on p. 77 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: This is when two vectors are conjugate. But what about the "field part"? I'm imaging this as a vector field with specific properties.

Comment: Start with a vector field $V$ and you create a conjugate direction field $W$ by doing this definition pointwise. (Note that, given $v$, $w$ is only defined up to scalar multiples at non-parabolic points.) If you want to share a more specific context, I'll be glad to listen :)

Comment: Maybe this? [PDF] Directional Field Synthesis, Design, and Processing - Stanford University
https://web.stanford.edu › ~diamanti › data

Comment: I thing the point is how I can construct a conjugate direction field, which is not a vector field. A vector field is a vector associated for each point in space. A direction field is like one or more lines per point. I struggle to find something which is easy enough to understand but complete enough so I can get an idea.

Comment: I got to the right place eventually, but you certainly didn't post a good link. :) In section 9.4 she gives precisely the definition I gave! As I already suggested, you get a direction field by saying you're orthogonal to a given vector — only by specifying that you want a unit vector forming a right-handed basis will you get a (smooth) conjugate vector field.

Comment: But what's the advantage of having things constructed in this way?

Comment: I don't understand your question. And I don't know what applications are in the paper you linked. But I did give a beautiful differential geometric application in the exercise I referred to —  given a curve in a surface, you can use the notion of conjugate directions to construct a flat ruled surface tangent to the surface along the curve .

Comment: Hi, with the reference to your second comment. Would be the first vector be chosen randomly? (but on the tangent plane of the surface at a point $p$)?

Comment: No, you start with the first vector field and refer to *its* conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

There's description of it here:

O. Diamanti, A. Vaxman, D. Panozzo, and O. Sorkine-Hornung. Designing n-polyvector fields with complex polynomials. In Computer
Graphics Forum, volume 33, pages 1–11. Wiley Online Library, 2014.